# Bug finder at your service

Tags: bug

Is it just me or are others experiencing issues with SF? Here's my latest, which occured when I clicked on the inbox button to read the message I apparently have: [image]

Answer (score 2):

I get this one daily. It happens when you click the notification before the page has finished loading. There must be some `$(document).ready({})` related to the button, that when it hasn't fired, you get that menu.

Comment: Nope, the page was fully loaded in this case. While I do sometimes click before the page has finished loading all that happens then is I get no drop-down at all. Of course the difference in what we're seeing may be browser dependent. Regardless, it's still a bug.

Comment: I get this semi-regularly for the same reason... Annoying.